Matrix representations and Einstein summation
According to Einstein summation convention, if we consider a matrix $A_{ij}$ as a $1-$upper,$1-$lower index object, i.e as $A^{i}_j$, we have the following transformation rule:
$$A^i_j B^j_k  = (AB)^i_k$$
where $j$ indicies are 'contracted', which is the matrix multiplication rule.
Now let's also consider another situation.
Let $T : V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator on a $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $F$. If we let $\mu = (v_1,\dots,v_n)$ and $\nu = (w_1,\dots,w_n)$ be two ordered bases for $V$, then there exists a map $T \mapsto T^{\mu}_{\nu}\in F^{n\times x}$ (a matrix) such that if
$$w = a_1w_1+\dots+a_nw_n$$
and $$Tw = b_1v_1+\dots+b_nv_n$$
then we have
$$T^{\mu}_{\nu}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a_1 \\
    a_2 \\
  \vdots \\
    a_n
\end{pmatrix}=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    b_1 \\
    b_2 \\
  \vdots\\
    b_n
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
That is $T^{\mu}_{\nu}$ is the matrix representation of $T$ w.r.t the given ordered bases,one for the domain and another for the codomain.
The key thing I want to mention is the following property:
Let $V$ be finite-dimensional, and $\mu, \nu, \sigma$ be ordered bases for $V$. Let $S, R : V\rightarrow V$ be linear operators. Then we have $$S^{\mu}_{\nu}R^{\nu}_{\sigma} = (S\circ R)^{\mu}_{\sigma}$$
which if everything was in not abstract but column like vector spaces, would correspond to saying something like $(B_{\mu}SB_{\nu}^{-1})(B_{\nu}RB_{\sigma}^{-1}) = B_{\mu}(SR)B_{\sigma}^{-1}$ where $B_{\tau}$ are coordinate change transformations.
My main question is as follows:
What other things have such property - they are multi index objects $T^{\mu_1\dots \mu_{r}}_{\nu_1 \dots \nu_{r}}$ such that  $T^{\mu_1\dots \mu_{r}}_{\nu_1 \dots \nu_{r}} S^{\nu_1\dots \nu_{r}}_{\sigma_1 \dots \sigma_{r}} = (TS)^{\mu_1\dots \mu_{r}}_{\sigma_1 \dots \sigma_{r}}$ for some notion of product between them. Is there a category for this objects? Are they important?
Note: Perhaps I am mentioning something that Linear Algebra instructors mention in the classes usually, and I think notation we would use for matrix representations were similar with upper and lower indices, but it never before occured to me characterize this objects. So, in case it is well-known, please note that I am also looking for the name of class of these sort of objects which is novel I think.
Note: Although I considered domain and codomain, equivalently number of upper and lower indices for multi-index objects same, the results for matrix multiplication and matrix representations could be generalized since $(m\times n)$ and $(n\times r)$ matrices can be multiplied and similarly $T: V\rightarrow W$ and $S: W\rightarrow U$ can be composed to give $S\circ T : V\rightarrow U$

If I understand your notation is correctly, these are linear maps $V^{\otimes n} \to V^{\otimes n}$, thought of as tensors of type $(n, n)$. We can of course consider more generally tensors of type $(r, s)$, which form a structure called a symmetric monoidal category with duals, which has various other names.

I think the matrix reps can be in that category, but the expression for matrix entries are  actually different because there is a sum that is not mentioned. Upto Einstein sums, can we join matrix entry returning functions as well to that category?
